# how to create table from sqlalchemy mapping

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following ORM mapping using SqlAlchemy:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    date_imported = Column(DateTime)
```

However, how can I either get the CREATE TABLE sql syntax or how I can I have it create the table for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Foo.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)` to issue the statement for that table, or `metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` to issue the statements for all tables registered on that metadata.  If you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, use `db.create_all()` to honor binds correctly.